# function argument types when get a value from an HTML element on react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

So Im just making a function that gets a value from an HTML element (LI tag). And this function will be called on an onClick event as well.

```
const getContents = (e: any) => {
  const data = e.target.textContent.split('some-separator') //.. and so on

  // other stuff
}

return (
  <li onClick={(e) => getContents(e)}>{some date}</li>
)
```

for the meantime, I'm putting `any` as I don't know and can't narrow the type for now. What would be the correct type for this, and when I try to put a fancy type - typescript would scream

> (property) Node.textContent: string | null - Object is possible 'null'

Answer (score 1):

```js
import {SyntheticEvent} from 'react'

const getContents = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
  // ...
}
// or more specific
const getContents = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  e.currentTarget.value
}
```